# Opensuse and Clonezilla: Cloned hard drive won't boot

Tags: linux, boot, opensuse, clone, clonezilla

Recently I used **Clonezilla** cloned one hard drive which I installed **Opensuse 12.2**, include all partitions. When I tried to restore it on another machine (with very similar hardware and same model of hdd), the hard drive won't boot. I just stuck at a black screen with a "-" sign blinking. No error or any message was given.

On the original machine, I have 1 hdd and 2 SSDs. I created partitions as `/`, `/home`, `/boot`, `swap`, and choose to use volume label instead of uuid or id in the `/etc/fstab`. The original system works perfectly but the cloned machine just won't boot.

I booted with Opensuse live cd to check out with `fdisk -l`, it shows that `/boot` was marked to be bootable, so it's supposed to boot.

When restore on the new machine, in Clonezilla chose "expert" mode there is a "reinstall grub" option, with or without this option been checked, the cloned system just won't boot.

Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 20170905-zesty release of Clonezilla seems to fix this issue, at least it did for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a way out.
The reason why cloned drive won't boot is that the hard drive is that there are drives not cloned exist in system and take positions of /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, but they don't have correct entries in fstab and Grub, so Grub can't boot. So I just change the cabling and make cloned drive be the first one, /dev/sda, and set this to target machine as well, then start to clone and restore without any problem. After restore, system can boot, because all new drives will be detected after /dev/sda, so the boot partition won't be influenced.